# IMAP Email issue - Not logging in with correct password

Tags: email, email-server, thunderbird

A little while ago, my email stopped working all of a sudden. The email is hosted on a cPanel server, and it seems to be just my accounts (I have 2 different emails, on 2 domains that are both not working), everyone elses accounts work fine.

It works fine on the Webmail in cPanel, but, when I try and use thunderbird, thunderbird tells me that my login information is incorrect, when, it's working fine with Webmail.

I checked /var/logs/maillog and I'm seeing a ton of entries like this:

```
May 6 18:23:09 zeta dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 3 attempts in 14 secs): user=<me@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=My.Home.IP, lip=the.server.IP, T LS, session=<8r9+sML4lABCHw5Q>
```

I've replaced my IP with `my.home.ip` in there, and the server IP with `server.ip`, as well as replaced the email with `me@example.com`

The IMAP server is Dovecot, and the server is running cPanel, cPHulk is disabled.

I've tried changing the Account password, deleting and readding the account, restarting all the email services, restarting cPanel, and restarting the server itself.. None of these have worked. I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure about cpanel , but if you look into this file:
**vi /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**

```
##
## Authentication processes
##

# Log unsuccessful authentication attempts and the reasons why they failed.
#auth_verbose = no

# Even more verbose logging for debugging purposes. Shows for example SQL
# queries.
#auth_debug = no

# In case of password mismatches, log the passwords and used scheme so the
# problem can be debugged. Requires auth_debug=yes to be set.
#auth_debug_passwords = no
```

changing to yes, you will see all information about your problem.